# Why using Stopwatch in Blazor Server App cause slower code execution

Tags: performance, blazor, blazor-server-side, stopwatch, .net-7.0

I have a Blazor Server App .Net7 with a single page with this code:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<button @onclick=OnCalcClick>Count</button>


<div>Elapsed Time: @time ms</div>
<div>Elapsed Time Stopwatch: @timeHigh ms</div>

@code{
    long result = 0;
    double time = 0;
    long timeHigh = 0;

    void OnCalcClick() {
        //Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        //s.Start();
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        for (long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            result ++;
        //s.Stop();
        var stop = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //timeHigh = s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        time = (stop - start).TotalMicroseconds;
    }
}
```

If I run the App in Release mode without debugging, I get the execution time about 250 ms.
If I comment using of DateTime and uncomment the Stopwatch, I get the execution time about 750 ms
If I uncomment everething, I get the same time with both measurement method and this time is about 750 ms.

I tried to do this multiple times, but results are the same.

So, it seems, Stopwatch makes the execution slower, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my test version of your code.  I:

1. Dropped the loop by an order of 10.
2. Separated out each test

I can't see any major difference in execution times.  Debug is slower, but that's expected.  What am I missing from your testing?

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>


<div class="alert alert-info">
    <div class="mb-2" >Elapsed Time: @time1 ms</div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @onclick=OnCalcClick>Count</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info">
    <div class="mb-2">Elapsed Time Stopwatch: @timeHigh2 ms</div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @onclick=OnCalcClickWithTimer>Count Timed</button>
</div>


<div class="alert alert-info">
    <div>Elapsed Time: @time3 ms</div>
    <div class="mb-2">Elapsed Time Stopwatch: @timeHigh3 ms</div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @onclick=OnCalcClickWithAll>Count Timed</button>
</div>

@code {
    long result1 = 0;
    double time1 = 0;

    long result2 = 0;
    double time2 = 0;
    long timeHigh2 = 0;

    long result3 = 0;
    double time3 = 0;
    long timeHigh3 = 0;

    void OnCalcClick()
    {
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            result1++;
        var stop = DateTime.UtcNow;
        time1 = (stop - start).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    void OnCalcClickWithTimer()
    {
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            result2++;
        s.Stop();
        timeHigh2 = s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    void OnCalcClickWithAll()
    {
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            result3++;
        s.Stop();
        var stop = DateTime.UtcNow;
        timeHigh3 = s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        time3 = (stop - start).TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Result in release mode:

[image]

And debug:

[image]